# Visual Studio Code Typescript task compile - output encoding

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc

There is a vscode typescript compilation task by manual:http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_transpiling-typescript-into-javascript.

After run build (Ctrl+Shift+B) vscode display tsc something with unknown encoding, see screen:
http://prnt.sc/dz60uu

**Any ideas?**

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "files": [
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module":"commonjs",
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "out": "dist/index.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This command fixed encoding problem:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Comment: Really helped. But what is the connection? Missing tsc?